# handling duplicate keys in HTTP post in order to specify multiple values

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

### Background

- python 2.7
- requests module
- http post with duplicate keys to specify multiple values

### Problem

Trevor is using python requests with a website that takes duplicate keys to specify multiple values. The problem is, JSON and Python dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys, so only one of the keys makes it through.

#### Goal

- The goal is to use python requests to create an HTTP post with duplicate keys for duplicate names in the POST name-value pairs.

#### Failed attempts

```
## sample code
payload = {'fname': 'homer', 'lname': 'simpson'
         , 'favefood': 'raw donuts'
         , 'favefood': 'free donuts'
         , 'favefood': 'cold donuts'
         , 'favefood': 'hot donuts'
         }
rtt = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

### See also

Web links:

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+requests

### Question

- How can Trevor accomplish this task using python requests?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can composite payload in this way:

```
payload = [
    ('fname', 'homer'), ('lname', 'simpson'),
    ('favefood', 'raw donuts'), ('favefood', 'free donuts'),
]
rtt = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

But if your case allows, I prefer POST a JSON with all 'favefoood' in a list:

```
payload = {'fname': 'homer', 'lname': 'simpson', 
    'favefood': ['raw donuts', 'free donuts']
}
# 'json' param is supported from requests v2.4.2
rtt = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", json=payload)
```

Or if JSON is not preferred, combine all 'favefood' into a string (choose separator carefully):

```
payload = {'fname': 'homer', 'lname': 'simpson',
    'favefood': '|'.join(['raw donuts', 'free donuts']
}
rtt = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: **// Or if JSON is not preferred, combine all 'favefood' into a string (choose separator carefully): //**

Have you tried this with the python requests library or do you have a reference to the source code or documentation that shows this is supported?

Comment: Did you ask about the JSON way or combined string way? Combine strings into a single one, and let `requests` to form-encode is the traditional way, you can see the usage example at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests. The "json" parameter was just added in 2.4.2 [changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/). Source codes also show the usage: `def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)` (https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py)

Comment: In older `requests` library, post a JSON can be done as: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers