# UrlFetchApp: how to simulate a HTTP post that have params with same name multiple times

Tags: http, google-apps-script, http-headers, http-post, mailgun

In an HTTP request one can specify most parameters multiple times, HTTP supports this out of the box. But how can this be done when using [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) of Google Apps Script?

I am trying to send mail using Mailgun API and want to attach multiple attachments. Here's what [Mailgun API says about this](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending):

> Note that you can specify most parameters multiple times, HTTP
>   supports this out of the box. This makes sense for parameters like cc,
>   to or attachment.

Here are some other similar questions related to other languages or platforms but none of these help:

- [Set more than one HTTP header with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241326/set-more-than-one-http-header-with-the-same-name)
- [Sending HTTP request with multiple parameters having same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835074/sending-http-request-with-multiple-parameters-having-same-name)
- [handling duplicate keys in HTTP post in order to specify multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116424/handling-duplicate-keys-in-http-post-in-order-to-specify-multiple-values)

Here's my code that works for a single attachment. Note that the function mailgun() takes exact same arguments as [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options) for consistency purposes:

```
function mailgun(recipient, subject, body, options){

var params = {
  "method":"POST",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode('api:key-goes-here')
  },
  "payload": {
    "to": recipient,
    "subject": subject,
    "text": body,
    "html": options.htmlBody
  },
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
};

if(options.hasOwnProperty("bcc"))
  params.payload.bcc = options.bcc;

if(options.hasOwnProperty("cc"))
  params.payload.cc = options.cc;

if(options.hasOwnProperty("replyTo"))
  params.payload['h:Reply-To'] = options.replyTo;

if(options.hasOwnProperty("name")){
  params.payload.from = options.name + ' <' + options.from + '>';
} else {
  params.payload.from = options.from;
}

if(options.hasOwnProperty("attachments")){
  params.payload.attachment = options.attachments[0];
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domain.com/messages', params);
var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
var responseObj = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

if(responseCode != 200) return 'Mailgun error: '+responseObj.message;  

return true;

}
```

If I use this code, the mail goes through but without attachments:

```
if(options.hasOwnProperty("attachments")){
  params.payload.attachment = [options.attachments[0],
                               options.attachments[1]
                              ];
}
```

The Mailgun API says 'You can post multiple attachment values'. This is a little misleading, as essentially they mean that 'you can specify attachment parameter multiple times' to send multiple attachments.

As payload is an object this is not possible using UrlFetchApp and I guess the only way is to manually build the multipart payload without relying on auto-generation of UrlFetchApp.

This is the Curl request that works. Need to emulate this using urlFetch:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-goes-here' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/domain.com/messages \
-F from='Support <support@domain.com>' \
-F to=example@domain.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
-F attachment='@image.png' \
-F attachment='@license.txt' \
```

Comment: Please add your code showing a successful test send with 1 attachment.

Comment: @PeterHerrmann I have edited my question with my current code that works only for the first attachment

Comment: The curl example is perfect. Please edit your Urlfetch example and replace it with a reproducible hardcoded (simplified) version showing a pass (1 attachment) and fail (2 attachment).

Comment: I posted a more broad version of this questions here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050972/urlfetchapp-how-to-simulate-multipart-curl-request-that-has-multiple-params-wit unfortunately it's down voted as being duplicate. You may want to refer to the link for more details.

Comment: @AkshayRaje did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @JackBrown now that I am re-looking at this, you can use FormData (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) and pass an array to it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax/28434829#28434829). Hope this helps!

Comment: @akshay_raje thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I did try them and only one attachment goes through when I pass two keys with the same name and none goes through if I pass an array of file blobs to the key attachment. But if you more suggestions, I am all ears!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I and solve it by manually encode the payload object into a string by applying the following function:

```
function jsonToUrlencoded(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        for (var i=0;i<obj[key].length;i++) {
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key][i]));
        }
      } else {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
      }
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

I used the code for an http request as in the following example:

```
  var payload={
    user_ID:2,
    action:'editpost',
    originalaction:'editpost',
    post_author:2,
    post_type:'post',
    original_post_status:'auto-draft',
    'post_category[]':[1,4,32]
  };
  options={
    method:'post',
    headers:cookies,
    payload:jsonToUrlencoded(payload),
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

Comment: what the structure of your `obj` ? I am trying to make it work...

Comment: It is a JSON object.

Comment: could you paste its structure? I created my own question. Maybe your answer answers this one too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68905786/250422

Comment: one more question. The code you provided is encoding attachments or the whole payload? Could provide all code related? So my question is whether the `obj` is object of payload or object of attachments. Could you give me code how you define attachments?

Comment: I paste the http request structure in the answer. In my case, I used an object of strings, integers and array of integers, but I never tested it with attachments.